# jQuery prop not working in iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, iframe

I have some very simple jQuery, in my Rails .erb file, and I cannot get it to work. My .erb file is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $('.check').prop('checked', true);
</script>

<%= bootstrap_form_for(@shipping_shop, layout: :inline) do |f| %>

<div class="input-lg check">
  <%= f.check_box :enabled, label: "Standard shipping enabled?" %>
</div>

.... stuff removed for brevity

<%= f.submit 'Save Standard Settings', class: 'btn btn-primary btn-lg 
btn-block' %>
<% end %>
```

My application.js file looks like this:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require bootstrap-sprockets
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
```

I'm using the "Rails Bootstrap Forms" gem. I can check the box by passing in arguments, but I am trying to figure out why I can't get any jQuery to work.

I am doing "[Setting "checked" for a checkbox with jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/426258/setting-checked-for-a-checkbox-with-jquery?rq=1)" exactly, but don't understand what's wrong.

I tried to change the `check` class directly to the element and that didn't work either:

```
<div class="input-lg check">
  <%= f.check_box :enabled, label: "Standard shipping enabled?",  
  class:"check" %>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you included `application.js` into the page in the iframe? Since a page in an iframe is a standalone page, it does not recognize the css files or javascript files included in the parent page.

Comment: Hmm, no I haven't.. How would I do that?

Comment: See your `app/views/layouts/application.erb` for example.

Answer (score 2):

Try loading the document first:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
 $('.check').prop('checked', true);
});
```

or:

```
 $( document ).ready(function() {
     $('.check').prop('checked', 'checked');
    });
```

Comment: Nope.. I wonder if its something with this gem, or somehow my setting in Ruby.. I can't find anything about a conflict with jquery and this gem though..

Comment: But you are loading the jquery library in the iframe page too, right? Couse the iframe document dont recognize elements/libraries from the parent document. (sorry for bad english)

Comment: That was it!! I wish I could give 2 correct answers.. I choose the one that was first.. But that was totally it!! Thank you!!

Comment: Nice!
I think you can add the comment with useful, it can help some others with this problem... im new here, dont understand the rules so mutch...

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
  $('.check').prop('checked', 'checked');
```

Comment: Where's this .check element, I see the div has class as "check". Maybe that's causing the problem

Comment: Geez, good idea.. but no I added the check class directly to the element.. and no dice.. I'll update the question